# OracleCommand.Executenonquery throws 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

The following function throws the `System.InvalidOperationException`:

```
internal void executeNonQuery(string connectionString, OracleCommand cmd)
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (cmd)
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //here is the error
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The additional information is:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

I try to insert a row into a table. Is there another way to do this or to fix this error?

**EDIT:** 
I build the query in the binaryManager class with the following methods:

```
internal object[] binaryInsert(string tblName, string tblQuery, int conStrgID, int cq)
    {
        object[] retValues = new object[3];
        Stream myStream = null ;
        OracleConnection con = null;
        string conString = qm.getConnectionString("ConnectionStringToMyDB"); //is correct

        byte[] data = GetBytes(tblQuery);

        String sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLES VALUES (NULL, '" + tblName + "', ':tblQueryBlob', " + conStrgID + ", " + cq + ")";


        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;  // Set the sql-command
        cmd.Connection = con;   //con is an OracleConnection

        OracleParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("tblQueryBlob", OracleDbType.Blob); //Add the parameter for the blobcolumn
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        param.Value = data;     //Asign the Byte Array to the parameter

        //command containts the parameter :tblQueryBlob with its value
        retValues[0] = cmd;
        retValues[1] = conString;

        return retValues;
    }

private byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
```

I call the binaryInsert method from another class with the following code:

```
BinaryManager bm = new bBinaryManager();
string sqlQuery = "large string with 5100 characters";
object[] binaryValues = bm.binaryInsert("TextTbl", sqlQuery, 1, 1);
string conString = binaryValues[1].ToString();
OracleCommand cmd = (OracleCommand)binaryValues[0];

QueryManager qm = new QueryManager();
qm.executeNonQuery(conString, cmd);
```

**EDIT2 (ExecuteReader):**

```
int csID = 1;
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(conString))
                {
                    using (OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        myCommand.Connection = conn; // FIX!
                        using(OracleDataReader read = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (read.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (read.Read())
                                {
                                    if (read[0] == System.DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        TableObject tableDBNull = new TableObject(csID, Convert.ToString(read[1]), (byte[])read[2], Convert.ToInt32(read[3]), Convert.ToInt32(read[4]));
                                        allTables.Add(tableDBNull);
                                        csID++;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        TableObject tableDBNNull = new TableObject(Convert.ToInt32(read[0]), Convert.ToString(read[1]), (byte[])read[2], Convert.ToInt32(read[3]), Convert.ToInt32(read[4]));
                                        allTables.Add(tableDBNNull);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        conn.Close();
                    }
```

The error happens in the if block: `if (read[0] == System.DBNull.Value)`

Comment: Can you provide your query too?

Comment: @ArtemKulikov post updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the Query (query errors raises exception from Oracle namespace).

In your case the command is not related to any connection.
You can solve it in some ways, i.e.

```
internal void executeNonQuery(string connectionString, OracleCommand cmd)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (cmd)
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn; // FIX!
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //here is the error
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Usually I prefere another way to do it

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
// Creating command from the connection
OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = ...........
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I have the same problem now with `myCommand.ExecuteReader()`. All should be fine and working and I have used nearly the same code as in your answer but I get the error..

Comment: If you post the piece of code I can have a look... Or try to work in the other way, create a connection than create the command using myConnection.CreateCommand()

Comment: I have updated my code. The other way would be the same as you have described above but with `cmd.ExecuteReader()`?

Comment: I think that the problem in this case is different. Probably is better if you open another issue and show the exception (is still InvalidOperationException? What is the message content?). I think in this case is related to the first field type so also the query and the table structure is important. Also, reading how you're using everything have also a look to DataTable object. Is filled automatically from a DataReader and is more simple to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You never connected your `Command` object to your `Connection` object.

You should pass in your parameters to this function and create a command here. You can then pass your connection in the command's constructor.

Putting an outside instance (function parameter) into a using block should raise a lot of red flags from the start. If you can, you should have the creation of the Disposable object in the using block. The point of the using block is to ensure that it gets disposed, if you construct the object before the block, you have a gap in your coverage.